# Expand const enums in JHipster webapp

Tags: java, typescript, enums, constants, jhipster

I'm working with a JHipster-generated project and I've used the JDL-Studio to create entities as well as enums.
My issue at the moment is that I want to be able to expand a list of enums. However my problem is that those are defined as constants in typescript as well as java (as they should be).

I just wanted to ask if there is an 'easy' way to **expand those const enums in the browser**. 
Or should I 'transform' my enums into an entity with JDL-Studio (which could be easier)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean expanding dynamically, i.e. a user can add enums from browser or REST API ? If so then yes, you can convert your enum into an an entity or into a string field rather than a related entity. Enums are static, they are like code.

For this conversion, to keep your custom changes, simplest would probably be to proceed like the [upgrade sub generator](http://www.jhipster.tech/upgrading-an-application/#step-by-step-explanation-of-the-upgrade-process) does by working on a git branch where you re-generate your entities and then merge them back to your master. It's like considering JHipster generator as another team member working on his branch.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Another question now: Can I use JDL-Studio in this case or should I do it "manually" by code? I already editet the entites so I do not want them to be reseted.

Comment: But you could also choose an easier way which is to convert your enum to a string field rather than a related entity.